# NPM install error ENOENT- Forked GITHUB

Tags: github, npm

I forked a github repo and made some change and tried to do npm install for my forked repo. I am getting the ENOENT error chmod 'C:\node_modules\js2coffee\out\bin\js2coffee'
is there something in package.json need to be updated for forked repos

```
npm install skandasoft/js2coffee
```

Answer (score 0):

js2coffee 2.0 has been released and should fix your `npm install` errors. Try installing it from upstream (`npm install js2coffee`), or forking the repo again.